# How to recreate the GitHub Network Graph

Tags: jquery, graph, github

Are there any open source projects out there or jQuery plugin that I can use to recreate the [GitHub Network Graph?](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer)

I want to create something with similar functionality.

Comment: login, go to your github repo, click on 'network'

Comment: @zack, that's better than what I was about to say, "view source" =)

Comment: nothing like good ol' developer sense of humor. - I checked out the source before I posted here, but it's so proprietary that it's impossible for me to reverse engineer it.  thats why i was hoping there was some os solution out there. - thanks for the tip though.

Comment: I'd imagine the solution involves looking at the commit objects in the repo and constructing a graph from the parent pointers.

Answer (score 23):

The Github network views seem very difficult to reverse engineer at first. However, the code becomes quite understandable after de-minifying it with http://jsbeautifier.org/ . So run `bundle_github.js` and `bundle_common.js` through and grab a jQuery 1.4.2 source. Then you're ready to start reading the source / debugging the page.

In the Github Network page, if the canvas is working, the network is generated simply by:

```
var ng = new Network("#ng", 920, 600)
```

which goes on to use an object generated by `defineNetwork(window.jQuery)`, which (among a lot of other things)

1. gets data from [the Github Network API](http://develop.github.com/p/network.html)
2. creates instances of `d.KeyDriver` and `d.MouseDriver` for handling input
3. uses `d.Chrome` to draw timeline, header and footer
4. uses `d.Graph` to write the network graph

*(each `d.ClassName` is an inner class of the Network object, thus their source is found inside the `defineNetwork` source code)*

I didn't take the time to really delve into the code and find all the details on how it works, but it's readable alright. Now depending on what you want to do, you could e.g.

- *(probably)* make very minor
  modifications to get the code to
  render Github data outside
  github.com
- make your own data available in [the Github Network API](http://develop.github.com/p/network.html) format, and visualize that
- adapt just the `d.Graph` class to work with your own data
- just read the code and learn

**NOTE: You probably can't legally use the code as-is nor modified, so I recommend doing this only for learning purposes (though IANAL).**

Comment: This seems to be now a broken link: http://develop.github.com/p/network.html
Did github remove that option?

Comment: @GuySoft the Github API has been updated over the last two years, and the details of this answer are now outdated. I'd guess the network graph nowadays uses the branches and forks APIs. Anyway, it's still easy to just grab the code, beautify it and see what it does.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to rely on **[Github's Network API](http://develop.github.com/p/network.html)** that handles:

> Listing all the data needed to draw the network graph, heads of every fork with new changes and all relevant commits.

As for the rendering, Github uses canvas to display its network graph.
You may want to have a look at the [**RaphaelJS** library](http://raphaeljs.com/) does a good job rendering the Github's impact graphs:
http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html

Comment: The link for the documentation for the network API is now a 404 page.  Is this obsolete? or is there a new link for this?

Comment: @MichaelT I assume this would now be http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/ ?